# Add Google map to table tr while spanning across all td's

Tags: html, angular

Sorry for title being little vague don't know how to put issue in words but anyways I have a little complex HTML table as shown below

```
<div *ngFor="let item of result; let i = index">
            <table
              datatable
              [dtOptions]="dtOptions2"
              class="table table-bordered mt-2"
              data-toggle="table"
            >
              <thead>
                <tr
                  attr.data-target="#collapsedata{{ i }}"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                  data-toggle="collapse"
                  style="cursor: pointer"
                >
                  <td colspan="4">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                    {{ item.name }}
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="collapse" id="collapsedata{{ i }}">
                  <th>Make</th>
                  <th>Model</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody class="collapse" id="collapsedata{{ i }}">
                <tr
                  *ngFor="let value of item.values"
                  (click)="RowSelected(value)"
                >
                  <td><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> {{ value.make }}</td>
                  <td>{{ value.model }}</td>
                  <td>{{ value.price }}</td>
                  <td>{{ value.date }}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

This table shows grouped items and then dropdown to grouped values as can be seen in image below
[image: Table].

I'm trying to integrate `Google Maps` with every row of data but when I try to add google maps to every `td` it obviously spans only 1 column like this

[image]

This is the code for above Image i'm using which works as it is

```
<td><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                     {{ value.make }}
                     <google-map
                     height="200px"
                     width="100%"
                     [zoom]="zoom"
                     [center]="center"
                     [options]="options"
                   ></google-map></td>
```

How can I achieve something like in the picture below for every `table row (tr)`.

[image: Maps]

Also I'm using `datatable` for sorting/Filtering purposes. Which I need as mistmatch of columns breaks `datatable`

Apologies for lengthy question and please let me know if any additional information is required.

I'm using `Angular 10`

Answer (score 1):

try to add one more **tr** for each item in **item.values**.

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let value of item.values">
      <tr (click)="RowSelected(value)">
          <td><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> {{ value.make }}</td>
          <td>{{ value.model }}</td>
          <td>{{ value.price }}</td>
          <td>{{ value.date }}</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <google-map></google-map>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: My apologies I forgot to mention, I'm using `datatable` for sorting/filtering functionality as adding additional `tr` throws an error, but displays wise it works

Answer (score 1):

Add the google map as normal, just have it in a `<td>` and use a `colspan=""` to span multiple columns

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">
        <google-map></google-map>
    </td>
</tr>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: My apologies I forgot to mention, I'm using `datatable` for sorting/filtering functionality as adding additional `tr` throws an error, but displays wise it works

Comment: Either way, you should be able to have a single `<td>` span multiple columns. I guess it depends on the data table library you're using

Comment: Yes that's what i mentioned as visually it works, but because of mismatch of headers and body, filtering/sorting breaks